# What are the binoculars/viewfinders for?

Tags: super-mario-3d-land

In various levels, you can find a viewfinder/binoculars that look like this: [image: binoculars]

What are they used for? You can stand behind them and look around the level, but is that all that they are for? That strikes me as a pretty strange thing for Nintendo to have added.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

When you look through them you are generally supposed to be looking for a toad, the toad will then throw a 1up or a star coin down for you. I think they were just added to take advantage of the gyroscope controls the 3DS has built in.

Answer (score 0):

Toad throws 1ups and gives you one out of the three of your stars for a specific level, so it's always a good thing to try to find him.